# Application of Boost Automatic Differentiation fails

Tags: c++, boost, derivative

I want to use the boost autodiff functionality to calculate the 2nd derivative of a complicated function.

At the boost help I can take a look on the following example:

```
#include <boost/math/differentiation/autodiff.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T fourth_power(T const& x) {
    T x4 = x * x;  // retval in operator*() uses x4's memory via NRVO.
    x4 *= x4;      // No copies of x4 are made within operator*=() even when squaring.
    return x4;     // x4 uses y's memory in main() via NRVO.
}

int main() {
    using namespace boost::math::differentiation;

    constexpr unsigned Order = 5;                  // Highest order derivative to be calculated.
    auto const x = make_fvar<double, Order>(2.0);  // Find derivatives at x=2.
    auto const y = fourth_power(x);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= Order; ++i)
        std::cout << "y.derivative(" << i << ") = " << y.derivative(i) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use this possibility to calculate a derivative in my class structure but I don't understand how. Here is a simplified code example of my .cxx file. I have a parametric equation which is seperated in two functions to get the x and y-coordinate. *radius* is a member variable. I want to calculate the second derivative of this parametric equation at a position *phi*.

```
#include <boost/math/differentiation/autodiff.hpp>

double
get_x_coordinate(const double phi) const {
    return (radius*cos(phi));
}

double
get_y_coordinate(const double phi) const {
    return (radius*sin(phi));
}

double
do_something(const double phi) const {
    auto const x = boost::math::differentiation::make_fvar<double, 2>(phi);
    auto fx = [this](auto x) { return get_x_coordinate(x); };
    auto fy = [this](auto x) { return get_y_coordinate(x); };
    auto const dx = fx(x);
    auto const dy = fy(x);
    return (dx.derivative(2)+dy.derivative(2));
}
```

This example fails because of the following error.

> cannot convert argument 1 from boost::math::differentiation::autodiff_v1::detail::fvar<RealType,10>' to 'const double'

I cannot change that get_x_coordinate and get_y_coordinate receive a const double and return a double because I use them in my code at other positions. So I don't really know how to continue.

Also I'm using Visual studio 2017. I ask myself what is the difference between

```
#include <boost/math/differentiation/autodiff.hpp>
```

and

```
#include <boost/math/differentiation/autodiff_cpp11.hpp>
```

Do I have to use cpp11 if I use VS2017? Both are available in my boost version.

Comment: Target functions must be templates working with `fvar`. Their content will be evaluated as an expression template.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment. Can you explain it a little bit more in detail please?

Comment: @user7860670 Is it also possible to pass a lambda? I still do not understand your comment. Also I still don't have a solution for the problem.

Comment: `fourth_power` in the first example is a `template` function while your functions are just regular functions accepting an argument of fixed type `double`. The boost works by passing an object of fancy `make_fvar<double, Order>(2.0)` type into the function which is not possible in case of `get_x_coordinate`. So in order for all this stuff to work you'll need to convert your functions into templates. Note that this will require writing custom `cos` and `sin` implementations (which should be templates as well).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This sounds really compliated to me just to get the second derivative. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I was wrong actually, there is no need to reimplement `cos` and `sin` because boost already provides convenient implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions of interest are to be converted into templates that may accept either `double` or boost fvar arguments. Note that boost provides custom implementations of trigonometric functions from standard library (such as sin, cos) suitable for `fvar`:

```
#include <boost/math/differentiation/autodiff.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

constexpr double const radius{4.0};

template <typename T>
T get_x_coordinate(T const & phi)
{
    return radius * cos(phi);
}

int main()
{
    double const phi{2.0};
    auto const x{::boost::math::differentiation::make_fvar<double, 2>(phi)};
    auto const dx{get_x_coordinate(x)};
    ::std::cout << dx.derivative(2) << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cboost/math/differentiation/autodiff.hpp%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0Aconstexpr+double+const+radius%7B4.0%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0AT+get_x_coordinate(T+const+%26+phi)%0A%7B%0A%09return+radius+*+cos(phi)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%09double+const+phi%7B2.0%7D%3B%0A%09auto+const+x%7B::boost::math::differentiation::make_fvar%3Cdouble,+2%3E(phi)%7D%3B%0A%09auto+const+dx%7Bget_x_coordinate(x)%7D%3B%0A%09::std::cout+%3C%3C+dx.derivative(2)+%3C%3C+::std::endl%3B%0A%09return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1301,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%271%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27178%27)),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Hi thanks, this works well with this easy dummy function. My problem now is that I have many functions with type double and as I understood I need to rewrite my hole programm as template functions. This would be very much work. There is really no way to easy get the second derivative with autodiff? If this is the case I'm thinking about using finite_differentiations of boost twice...

Comment: I'm afraid no, it won't work without converting functions to templates first.

Comment: Then I say thank you very much. Answer is accepted since the question is answered. I appreciate your help!